# How to get more synonyms using NLTK Wordnet?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

So I am using this code to get the synonyms.

```py
from nltk.corpus import wordnet 

def Get_Syn(text):
    xx = []
    sentence1 = text.split(" ")
    for i in sentence1:
        if i not in stopwords:
            for syn in wordnet.synsets(i):
                for name in syn.lemma_names():
                      if name != i.lower():
                               xx.append({i:name}) 
                      else: 
                        pass
    return xx
```

Now, if I use `Get_Syn('recieve')`, I recieve an empty list (no synonyms). But, if I use 
`Get_Syn('get')`, this is the list I get:

```
[{'get': 'acquire'},
 {'get': 'become'},
 {'get': 'go'},
 {'get': 'let'},
 {'get': 'have'},
 {'get': 'receive'},
 {'get': 'find'},
 {'get': 'obtain'},
     .
     .
     .
]
```

As we see, `recieve` is a synonym of `get`, but `get` is not a synonym of `recieve`.

So how can I get `get` when I search for `recieve`. Is there way to map the two together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function is right.
you have vocab error to write receive.
recieve is wrong please check your word again.

```
Get_Syn('receive')

[
 {'receive': 'have'},
 {'receive': 'get'}, <===
 {'receive': 'find'},
 {'receive': 'obtain'},
 ...
```